# Efficient way to generate a list of missing elements given another list?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list with the elements `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

If I have another list that contains elements of the mainlist such as `[1,2]` or `[2,4,5]`, what's an efficient way to generate new lists with the missing numbers, so that:

`[1, 2]` utilizing `[1,2,3,4,5]` would give `[3, 4 ,5]`

`[2, 4, 5]` utilizing `[1,2,3,4,5]` would give `[1, 3]`

I was thinking of using a nested for-loop to check, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way or built-in function that can be used in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `.Except`. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__)

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5 };

var missing = list1.Except(list2).ToList();

missing.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));

>> 2    4
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks for providing the Docs too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `HashSet` ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2))

```
var hash = new HashSet<int>(new int[] {1, 2});
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var missing = list.Where(x => !hash.Contains(x)); // 3, 4, 5;
```

Good thing about using a HashSet is that `Contains` should be an O(1) operation.